# What's the correct term for when a small problem becomes a big problem?

Tags: single-word-requests, doubled-words

What's the correct term for when a small problem becomes a big problem?  An example would be what happens to Larry David on "Curb Your Enthusiasm"...

Comment: *Larry David on "Curb Your Enthusiasm"* Not a very helpful example for those who don't know who Larry David is or what "Curb Your Enthusiasm" is.

Comment: Perhaps so, but that seemed to be the epitome of what he does.  I'll attempt to find another example...

Comment: ...maybe _snowball_, but I do not know if this is "correct" enough for you.

Comment: Informally, go from bad to worse, or “out of the frying pan into the fire”.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **escalation** would cover it. This can describe many things, such as an argument, become more serious:

> to increase in extent, volume, number, amount, intensity, or scope
>
> *a little war threatens to escalate into a huge ugly one*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escalate)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest the word ***Intensify.***

[**Intensify**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intensify) (Verb)

> to become greater, more serious, or more extreme, or to make something do this
>
> > When industrial restructuring accelerated in the 1980s, labor-management relations problems intensified.

Answer (score 0):

***[Get out of hand](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+out+of+hand)*** is an idiomatic expression that may be of help here:

> if a problem/situation get out of hand they become difficult or impossible to control.
>
> - The student teacher saw that the class was getting completely out of hand, so he asked for help.

(The Free Dictionary)